# How to log out from Facebook on iPhone (native/integration)

Tags: iphone, facebook, integration, logout

This is so silly. How do I log out from Facebook, or switch to another user, on iPhone running iOS 6/7?

When I logged out from my Facebook account using the Facebook app, I was still logged in natively on the iPhone: for example, if I go to Photos and tap on share, I'm still logged in to Facebook with my integrated account.

I could not find any place in the Settings to log out from Facebook (integration). The closest I came was Settings->Facebook->(my name)->Delete Account but that seems a bit harsh.

I must be missing some simple way to do this. I even tried Siri and told her: "Log out from Facebook". She replied: "Surely you mean Goodbye?". When I answered: "Yes", she said: "That's what I figured" and nothing happened. LOL.

Comment: The `Delete Account` is accutally logout, it means to delete your account from device not delete your Facebook Account.

Comment: Thanks @rckoenes: Couldn't have figured it out myself. I guess they really don't want users ever logging out by choosing such a text for that button...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the top left of your news feed, you'll see a "list" button that expands into a detailed menu. At the very bottom, there is a set of account settings; the last of which allows you to log out of your account. This is version 6.4, on iOS7.

If it isn't logging you out, you have possibly connected your phone to your Facebook account. You can change this in the Settings app; logging out of both of these will solve your problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Varada. Actually it was the Settings->Facebook->(my name)->Delete Account button that "disconnects" the phone's integrated facebook account. It's just that "Delete Account" is such a strong choice of words that I didn't want to press it before knowing what it will actually do.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 7.0.4, iPhone 4S.  In the Facebook app from the News Feed screen, there is a menu in the lower right with the word "More".  Click on it and you get a long menu.  At the very bottom of that menu should be a "Log out" button.

Why is this so hard to find?

Answer (score -2):

None of these answers worked for me.  How how could it be just to LOG OUT of Facebook?  I just deleted it completely and installed it again.  Why does this have to be so complicated?

Comment: This isn't the answer